# Non-principal ideals in cyclotomic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb Q(\xi_{39})$ be the 39-th cyclotomic field. Pari-GP told me that the prime ideals above $3$ and $13$ are not principal. Is there a way to prove that by hand (no computation made by computer)

Comment: There are no prime ideals above 39. You meant prime ideals over 3 and 13. Can you compute the class number by hand?

Comment: Indeed, this is a type. I meant $13$. I know that the class number is $2$ (I used the table given in Washington book "Cyclotomic fields").

Comment: If you are willing to accept a table entry from a book without checking it yourself, why not accept what a computer tells you too? :) Since you believe $h = 2$, if two ideals are not principal then their product must be principal, so check first that there is an element whose norm is the product of norms of primes over 3 and 39 (norms from a cyclotomic field down to $\mathbf Q$, other than $\mathbf Q$ itself, are never negative). That would show you do not have to check that primes over both 3 and 39 are not principal, but just over one of them.

Comment: Here is a way: Assume the prime ideal to be principal say generated by a cyclotomic integer $\alpha$. Calculate the norm of the prime above. Then the $|N(\alpha)|$, is also norma of a suitable integer in a quadratic subfield. Choose an imaginary quadratic subfield in $Q[\zeta_{39}]$, where the norm is a positive definite quadratic form; for a binary form it should be easy to check if it assumes a specific value or not.

Comment: @Vanchinathan:Why is  |N(α)| norm of a suitable integer in a quadratic subfield? Moreover, there is only one quadratic subfield in a cyclotomic field. So how do you choose it?

Comment: @joaopa, the norm is transitive, so if you have a tower of finite extensions $L/K/F$ then for $\alpha \in L$ we have ${\rm N}_{L/F}(\alpha) = {\rm N}_{K/F}({\rm N}_{L/K}(\alpha))$. Thus the norm from $L$ to $F$ of any element of $L$ is *also* the norm from $K$ to $F$ of a related element of $K$ for any field $K$ between $L$ and $F$. (Your previous comment says there is only one quadratic subfield in a cyclotomic field, but surely you meant "possibly more than one" in general, since the Galois group $({\mathbf Z}/n)^\times$ often has more than one subgroup of index two.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The quadratic number field $k = {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-39})$ has a cyclic class group of order 
$4$. Its genus field is  $K = {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{13})$, which has class number $2$.
The  Hilbert class field of $K$ is dihedral over ${\mathbb Q}$, hence not contained in the
cyclotomic field $L = {\mathbb Q}(\zeta_{39})$. This already shows that the class number of $L$ is even.

Now verify that one of the prime ideals above $13$ in $K$ is not principal (obvious since 
its norm down to $k$ is not principal) and that it ramifies completely in $L/K$.